# Display search result on top of the last search result

Tags: apex, lightning

I have a lightning component that displays a text box and a search button. On entering a string in the text box, system checks if the string is present in the text__c field of Case object & returns the matching Case record. When i make another search with different string, the component refreshes and matching Case record is returned. However, i want to display the search result in addition to the previous search result. For eg: if my previous search returned 4 Cases, and my new search returns 5 Cases, I want to display all 9 Accounts. Any idea how can I achieve this?

Please find the code below:

## searchCaseController.apxc-

```
public with sharing class searchCaseController {

 @AuraEnabled
 public static List < case > fetchCase(String searchKeyWord, Id recId) { 
  List < case > returnList = new List < case > (); 
  List < case > lstOfCase =[Select AccountId,CaseNumber,CreatedDate,text__c from case where text__c LIKE: searchKeyWord and AccountId=:recId];
  for (Case acc: lstOfCase) {
   returnList.add(acc);

  }
  return returnList;
 }
}
```

## component-

```
<aura:component controller="searchCaseController" implements="force:hasRecordId,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes,force:lightningQuickAction" access="global">   

    <!-- CREATE ATTRIBUTE/VARIABLE-->
    <aura:attribute name="searchResult" type="List" description="use for store and display account list return from server"/>
    <aura:attribute name="searchKeyword" type="String" description="use for store user search input"/>
    <aura:attribute name="Message" type="boolean" default="false" description="use for display no record found message"/>
    <aura:attribute name="TotalNumberOfRecord" type="integer" default="0" description="use for display Number of records"/>

    <!-- SHOW LOADING SPINNER--> 
    <lightning:spinner variant="brand" size="large" aura:id="Id_spinner" class="slds-hide" />

    <div class="slds-m-around_medium">
       <!-- SEARCH INPUT AND SEARCH BUTTON--> 
        <lightning:layout>
            <lightning:layoutItem size="3" padding="around-small">
               <!-- <lightning:input value="{!v.searchKeyword}" -->
                 <lightning:input value="{!v.searchKeyword}"
                                 required="true"
                                 placeholder="search cases...."
                                 aura:id="searchField"
                                 label="Account Name"/>
            </lightning:layoutItem>
            <lightning:layoutItem size="2" padding="around-small">
                <lightning:button onclick="{!c.Search}"
                                  variant="brand"
                                  label="Search"
                                  iconName="utility:search"/> 
            </lightning:layoutItem>
        </lightning:layout>

        <!-- TOTAL RECORDS BADGES--> 
        <div class="slds-m-around_x-small">
            <lightning:badge label="{!v.TotalNumberOfRecord}" />
        </div>

        <!-- ERROR MESSAGE IF NOT RECORDS FOUND--> 
        <aura:if isTrue="{!v.Message}">
            <div class="slds-notify_container slds-is-relative">
                <div class="slds-notify slds-notify_toast slds-theme_error" role="alert">
                    <div class="slds-notify__content">
                        <h2 class="slds-text-heading_small">No Records Found...</h2>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </aura:if>

        <!-- TABLE CONTENT--> 
        <table class="slds-table slds-table_bordered slds-table_cell-buffer">
            <thead>
                <tr class="slds-text-title_caps">
                    <th scope="col">
                        <div class="slds-truncate" title="S.no">S.no</div>
                    </th>
                    <th scope="col">
                        <div class="slds-truncate" title="Account Name">Account Name</div>
                    </th>
                    <th scope="col">
                        <div class="slds-truncate" title="CaseNumber">CaseNumber</div>
                    </th>
                    <th scope="col">
                        <div class="slds-truncate" title="CreatedDate">CreatedDate</div>
                    </th>
                    <th scope="col">
                        <div class="slds-truncate" title="Text">Text</div>
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody> 
                <!--### display all records of searchResult attribute by aura:iteration ###-->
                <aura:iteration items="{!v.searchResult}" var="acc" indexVar="count">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <div class="slds-truncate">{!count + 1}</div>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <div class="slds-truncate">{!acc.AccountId}</div>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <div class="slds-truncate">{!acc.CaseNumber}</div>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <div class="slds-truncate">{!acc.CreatedDate}</div>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <div class="slds-truncate">{!acc.text__c}</div>
                        </td> 
                    </tr>
                </aura:iteration>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</aura:component>
```

## controller.js-

```
({
    Search: function(component, event, helper) {

        var searchField = component.find('searchField');
        var isValueMissing = searchField.get('v.validity').valueMissing;
        // if value is missing show error message and focus on field
        if(isValueMissing) {
            searchField.showHelpMessageIfInvalid();
            searchField.focus();
        }else{
          // else call helper function 
            helper.SearchHelper(component, event);            
        }
        event.preventDefault();
    },
})
```

## helper.js-

```
({
    SearchHelper: function(component, event) {
        // show spinner message
         component.find("Id_spinner").set("v.class" , 'slds-show');
        var action = component.get("c.fetchCase");
        action.setParams({
            'searchKeyWord': component.get("v.searchKeyword"),
            'recId': component.get("v.recordId")
        });
        action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
           // hide spinner when response coming from server 
            component.find("Id_spinner").set("v.class" , 'slds-hide');
            var state = response.getState();
            if (state === "SUCCESS") {
                var storeResponse = response.getReturnValue();

                // if storeResponse size is 0 ,display no record found message on screen.
                if (storeResponse.length == 0) {
                    component.set("v.Message", true);
                } else {
                    component.set("v.Message", false);
                }

                // set numberOfRecord attribute value with length of return value from server
                component.set("v.TotalNumberOfRecord", storeResponse.length);

                // set searchResult list with return value from server.
                component.set("v.searchResult", storeResponse); 

            }else if (state === "INCOMPLETE") {
                alert('Response is Incompleted');
            }else if (state === "ERROR") {
                var errors = response.getError();
                if (errors) {
                    if (errors[0] && errors[0].message) {
                        alert("Error message: " + 
                                    errors[0].message);
                    }
                } else {
                    alert("Unknown error");
                }
            }
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    },
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just concatenate the results together:

```
var storeResponse = component.get("v.searchResult").concat(response.getReturnValue());
```

The remainder of your code can stay the same.

Note: Make sure you initialize the list beforehand, or you'll get an error:

```
<aura:attribute default="[]"
                name="searchResult" 
                type="List" 
                description="use for store and display account list return from server"/>
```

Comment: Is there a way to find out if a user is making unique searches in the above search box?

Comment: @user51241 You could keep track of the previous searches in a list attribute. If you get stuck, perhaps consider asking a new question.